# Drawing images finishes "prematurely" in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, image, memorystream

I am writing a puzzle program with some image processing applications.
I have a two-dimensional array of bitmap- every element in the array is a piece of the puzzle.
I also have an Image objects array matching the bitmaps array respectively.
I use a memory stream to convert the bitmap objects to image objects.

However, when it comes to drawing the picture to the screen, it seems like, the image is put into the screen way before it is actually finished reading from the stream. it looks like this:
[image: Seems like image is not read completely]

In addition, when i try to divide my picture into more pieces, it seems like it works fine.
like this:
[image: Divided into more pieces]

my hunch

here is the relevant code:

```
 BitmapImage [,] bitImageArr = new BitmapImage [vertPcs, horzPcs];
        Image[,] imageArr = new Image[vertPcs, horzPcs]; 
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
          for(int i=0; i<horzPcs;i++)
              for (int j = 0; j < vertPcs; j++)
              {
                  board.pieces[j, i].Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                  ms.Position = 0;
                  bitImageArr[j, i] = new BitmapImage();                   
                  bitImageArr[j, i].BeginInit();
                  bitImageArr[j, i].StreamSource = ms;
                  bitImageArr[j, i].EndInit();

                  imageArr[j,i] = new Image();
                  imageArr[j,i].Source = bitImageArr[j, i];
                  imageArr[j, i].SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, j);
                  imageArr[j, i].SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, i);
                  mainGrid.Children.Add(imageArr[j, i]);

              }
        mainGrid.ShowGridLines = true;
```

my hunch is that it has something to do with threading synchronization, yet i'm not sure and looking for a more professional answer.
does any one have any idea what is the cause for it and how to fix it??

Comment: Could it be anything to do with recycling the memory stream in the loop? Have you tried newing up the memory stream inside the for loop?

Comment: It seems to be happening consistently in the same location.

And you say you think it may have to do with threads... are there any threads that you are using that we should know about?

Also, do you need to store all of the BitmapImages... do you use these later? If not, you can just create a new one and use it for the image, and not worry about it.

Comment: In addition to what Charleh has said, you should also call `bitImageArr[j,i].CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;` before EndInit.

Comment: the CacheOption adition worked it out. Thank you guys for your help. This community is indeed amazing.

Comment: It also had nothing to do with threading. It was some kind of problem with the stream( which one...?). I fixed by instantiating the stream inside the loop,so a the stream would be open at the begining of every iteration and closed it at the end of it. That way i got different pieces showing at every iteration and not the same piece time after time as it shows in the pictures.